# Displaying values as selected state within option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fighting somewhat to get my output in AllGroups - Group 1 to appear as the selected item in my option value within the returned group_html.

Can anyone help?

```
    var existing_groups = $.map(calEvent.users, function(group){
        return group.group_id;
    });

    var group_html = $.map(calEvent.AllGroups, function(group) {
        return '<option value="G|' + group.id + '"' + ((existing_groups.indexOf(group.id) > -1) ? ' selected ' : '') + '>' +
                'Group: ' + group.name +
            '</option>';
    }).join('');

    return group_html;

    // calEvent.users (output)
    // 175833: {id: "22322", group_id: "545",  name: "Group 1"}
    // 175834: {id: "22323", group_id: "534", name: "Group 2"}

    //calEvent.AllGroups (output)
    //0: {id: "22322",  name: "Group 1" }
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: What denotes a group as "selected"? What does the correct result look like?